# Automation turn on setting Chat Externally on Google Workspace for some Organizational Units

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

My organization just switched to Google Workspace. Currently I need to reconfigure the settings for some Organizational Units.

In which I need to turn on **Chat externally** in *"**Apps > Google Workspace > Settings for Google Chat and classic Hangouts > External Chat Settings**"* for some Organizational Units.

Since there are quite a few Organizational Units that need to be turned on, I can't do it manually. So I researched some methods to automate this. However it cannot meet my requirements.

Methods that I try:

First I tried using ***[GAM command line tool](https://github.com/GAM-team/GAM/wiki)***, but after reading the Wiki as well as experimenting, I found that this tool does not have any modules that meet my needs.

Next, I tried using **Google App Script** as well as writing a tool in Python to interact with the ***Workspace Admin SDK***, but I couldn't find any API that would support this configuration.

Tks and regards

Comment: Please share the Apps Script you tried.

Comment: I just tested AppScript, to get a list of users, but I haven't found an API to turn on according to my needs